# Using Fiddler to capture few important Details

Tags: proxy

I want to implement the following requirement.

In an online Bank Transaction, a User wants to send an amount of $1000 to an Account A. I want to see that the request is going unmodified to Banking Server. So, I am using a Proxy Server as Fiddler n Client Side where the user enters Account and Amount information. Upon clicking submit, the proxy will reconfirm the Account and amount details before it sends to Server. So, I want to achieve this using Fiddler on client side. Is it possible with Fiddler? Or Is there any better Proxy that can do what I want? kindly let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: When you say implement, are you looking to do this for yourself or automate it for multiple users?

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler would be the right choice for a client-based proxy implementation I guess, and it can be used as a stand-alone application or embarked in your application code (the user browser in your case).

However, if you want to do this as a protection measure, you should consider this as weak as a javascript control. Everything running on client-side can be tamperred and Fiddler is no exception to that.

Comment: So, you think Fiddler cant do the thing I wanted? moreover, I didn't get the Source code of Fiddler to tweak a bit .pls comment

Comment: Although you **can** implement what you want with Fiddler, this will still be a *client-side control*, hence subject to tampering attacks on the client itself (just like any javascript control for example). Also, this will **not** guarantee you that the request goes unmodified to the server, instead it will only tell you that the request was not altered at the time it went through Fiddler, and tampering can still happen later in the process.